# Specification of longitudinal mixed-effects model with varying treatment times, varying observation times in lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme, treatment-effect

I am familiar with fixed-effects linear regression models, and have done reading on mixed-effects models.

I am attempting to fit a model based on observational data, where treatments come at varying times and do not exist at all for a majority of subjects.

I am interested in whether or not the treatment has an effect on the trajectory of a subject's response over time. Graphically:

[image: Varying treatment time mixed model]

The most relevant analogous model I have found would be the one specified [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/seminars/mlm_longitudinal/), specifically Part 3. However, this example does not use R. I have read through all of Bates' lme4 paper, but I am still uncertain how to specify this effect.

An excerpt of my data:

```
     ID RESPONSE ID.CONST.1 ID.VAR.1 ID.VAR.2 TREATMENT_ACTIVE RESPONSE.TIME
1077415        7         41        0        5            FALSE           314
1077415        8         41        1        6            TRUE            316
1077415        9         41        10       7            TRUE            319
1077688        1         59        0        1            FALSE           313
1079475        1         85        0        1            FALSE           313
1080811        1         24        0        1            FALSE           314
1081156        1        502        0        1            FALSE           314
1082437        1         50        0        0            FALSE           315
1083154        1        257        0        0            FALSE           315
1083154        2        257        0        0            TRUE            316
1083527        1         69        0        0            FALSE           315
1086283        1         31        0        0            FALSE           316
1088810        1        120        2        1            FALSE           317
1090019        1         93        2        1            TRUE            317
1091048        1         27        0        0            FALSE           317
1091114        1         62        0        1            FALSE           317
```

Each subject (`ID`) has time-varying measurements (`ID.VAR.X`), constant measurements (`ID.CONST.X`), as well as the time of observation (`RESPONSE.TIME`). `TREATMENT_ACTIVE` indicates whether or not the treatment is active for a given subject at the corresponding `RESPONSE.TIME`. Some subjects have a single observation, others have multiple observations, and treatment times are rarely the same between subjects.

I've attempted to fit models as:

```
lmer(RESPONSE ~ ID.CONST.1 + ID.VAR.1 + ID.VAR.2 + TREATMENT_ACTIVE + RESPONSE.TIME + (1|ID) + (1|RESPONSE.TIME)
lmer(RESPONSE ~ ID.CONST.1 + ID.VAR.1 + ID.VAR.2 + RESPONSE.TIME + (1|ID) + (1+TREATMENT_ACTIVE|RESPONSE.TIME)
```

However, I'm fairly certain this is misspecified. I am not sure how to specify the random effects to ensure that the `TREATMENT_ACTIVE` variable is interpreted as I intend. I am interested in testing both an intercept-only model as well as a intercept+slope model for the treatment effect.

Comment: I apologise for the very brief answer below. I found your question while I was looking for something slightly different. I hope to update the answer with an example very soon.

Comment: Be careful with the correlation structure you are assuming.  Check the within-subject correlations it applies against a plot of observed correlations or make a semivariogram.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your description whether the intervention occurs at the same time for all individuals, or whether there is a time-dependency in the intervention. In any case, Chapters 5 and 6 of the book, *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis* by Singer and Willet would seem to cover exactly what you want. In fact, you almost got to the right place with the link you included! Have a look at the R code for chapteres 5 and 6 at the [website](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/examples/alda.htm) for the Singer and Willet book.  Also, search for "discontinuous time".

Comment: Thank you very much. The intervention occurs at different times for various individuals; there is a time-dependency in the intervention. I will read the mentioned book and accept your answer if it is indeed what I'm looking for. Again, thank you very much for reading my long-winded question and answering!